# How to Use Flask_login with Flask and MySQLdb connector

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-login

For the most part of my project, I have developed my Flask app using MySQLdb connector. And now I am developing a login page and I prefer to use Flask_login for the login application. However, it seems that Flask_login requires a db.model using SQLalchemy to successfully pass the user object to login_user. Is there a possible way out to use Flask_login with MySQLdb connector? Has anyone been successful in doing so?

It is going to take me time to rewrite my Flask application using SQLalchemy instead. WOuld be great if there is a way to solve this without rewriting the full application.

Thanks in advance!